# Rsync Library in Objective-C

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin, rsync

I'm developing a mac application that need to use Rsync algorithm. However I need to use some functions such as generating signature, generating delta and patch delta.

```
GenerateSignature(Stream oldFile, Stream outSignature)
GenerateDelta(Stream signature, Stream newFile, Stream outDelta)
PatchFile(Stream oldFile, Stream delta, Stream outNewFile)
```

I have a C# implementation of this algorithm and I need to work with both of them. They need to be able to change deltas and signatures between each other.

I was wondering if I could use that C# library through maybe Xamarin or any other ways for it ? Or are there any native Objective-C library available for this job.